# jQuery.text correct usage

Tags: jquery

It's going to be something simple, but with the code below, I am getting the alert to output "VOID" but my second line of jQuery does not result in anything happening. What is the correct syntax for getting an action to occur based on some text within an ID?

HTML:

```
<span id="door1status">VOID</span>
```

jQuery:

```
alert ($('#door1status').text());

if ($('#door1status').text() == 'VOID') { // do something
};
```

Comment: 30% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Either my questions aren't answered or the site doesn't let me select an answer cos I'm "too new", etc! I'm not even allowed to vote up useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work fine, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAYjt/) to see it working.

Make sure in the HTML code you have that there is only 1 element in the page with the `id` of `door1status`. Repeated `id` attributes are invalid and will cause issues like this.

Comment: Thank you both for looking into this for me - I sort of fibbed, my HTML is not

    <span id="door1status">VOID</span>

But is actually:

    <span id="door1status"><?php echo stripslashes($lines[0]); ?></span><br>

It is getting the data from an external file, and whilst I thought it was outputting "VOID" it is actually outputting "VOID (line break here)". Manually replacing the PHP with "VOID" executes the alert. I just need to look into getting rid of that line break now. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly.

The `.text()` method returns the text-only content of the element as a string.

You're code is working correctly.

You can check the same at the is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GB46/).

Since this is not the problem the likely issues could be:

1. You have more than one element with the `#door1status` id on the page
2. jQuery is not loaded. (since alert is plain ol' JS but .text() isn't)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - please see my response to Rory's answer.

Comment: @Chris no worries mate, glad we could help

Answer (score 0):

You have not added anything to happen in your second line of code, at least put some alert

```
if ($('#door1status').text() == 'VOID') { 
    alert("TEXT"+$('#door1status').text());
};
```